# EntityFramework and SQL Server Remove Related Entity

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am having a weird issue with my understanding of Entity Framework.

I have the following sample objects recording as data in my SQL Database.

```
public class Competition 
{
    public long Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SeasonCompetition 
{
    public long Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Competition Competition { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I create a new instance of `Competition` and save it to the database.
I then create a new instance of `SeasonCompetition` relating to the created `Competition`.

```
Competition competition = new Competition();
competition.Name = "Test";
_context.Add(competition);
_context.SaveChanges();

SeasonCompetition seasoncompetition = new SeasonCompetition();
seasoncompetition.Name = "Test Season Comp";
seasoncompetition.Competiton = competition;
_context.Add(seasoncompetition);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

This successfully writes a record to the `SeasonCompetitions` table looking a bit like this.

| Id | Name | SeasonCompetitionId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test Season Competition | 1 |

Now, I want to remove the relationship so this `SeasonCompetition` does not relate to the `Competition` record

```
seasoncompetition.Competition = null;
_context.Update(seasoncompetition);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

If I put a breakpoint in and examine the `seasoncompetition` object after `SaveChanges()`, I can see `seasoncompetition.Competition = null`, but looking at the database, it still shows this.

| Id | Name | SeasonCompetitionId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test Season Competition | 1 |

How do I update the `SeasonCompetition` record to remove the relationship to `Competition` but still keep the `Competition` record in place in the database?

Using Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 5

Comment: Did you type this code out manually rather than copying it from a working, compiling/running program? It has typos that should prohibit compilation

Comment: as far I can see there is no link, the example you showed has no visible relations. The `Id` is autoincremented i suppose? And the `SeasonCompetitionId` is the `Id` from your poco? Could you clarify where you see a link between `Competition` and `SeasonCompetition`

Comment: @rbdeenk on the contrary, the relations are inferred based on naming conventions. Otherwise EF wouldn't even insert those records

Comment: We don't know if Matthew has bound the columns in the startup. So I figured this was the case

Comment: @MatthewWarr there's no reason to call `SaveChanges` twice. EF persists all pending changes when you call `SaveChanges` *and* takes care of database generated IDs and related entities. That's not the cause of the problem, but EF *depends* on either calling `SaveChanges` just once to commit all changes, or discard the DbContext to "roll back" by *not* committing anything

Comment: It was typed, to provide slimmed down examples rather than copy-paste

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed, I have used that before but I have also found that it doesn't record the Ids correctly in some instances, so I always save the changes between related entities to avoind any potential issue

Comment: Do you use EntityFramework or EF Core? Is there any special setup of the DbContext? Is the relationship between the entities customized somehow? If I create a database with EFCore 5 and run your code, everything works as expected.

Comment: Which EF version (please use the appropriate tag). Is `_context` always the same instance?

Comment: If you want to get something useful out of your bounty you better respond to comments. As said, in EF 5 there's no problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/) - make 'Competition' [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwith-nrt#required-and-optional-properties):

```
public class SeasonCompetition
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Competition? Competition { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Only applies if nullable reference types are enabled. But even then it doesn't make a difference. Without a non-nullable primitive FK property (like int CompetitionId) EF already implements the FK as nullable.

Comment: Are you sure that NRTs make no difference? My tests showed the required behavior.  [starting with .net 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) nullable reference types get default and it's just a backward thing not to use them.

Comment: OP is using .net 5 and *probably* (still not clear) EF-core 5.

Comment: If you want to use nullable convention in ef core: opt in to nullable reference types if you still use .net 5 ... A detail that is in the linked doc.

Answer (score -1):

Calling `_context.Update(seasoncompetition)` doesn't do anything in this case.
This is how you should do it:

```
        //create
        var competition = new Competition
        {
            Name = $"Competition {DateTime.Now.Millisecond}"
        };
        _context.Competitions.Add(competition);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        var season = new SeasonCompetition
        {
            Competition = competition,
            Name = $"Season {DateTime.Now.Millisecond}"
        };
        _context.SeasonCompetitions.Add(season);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        //Created season & competition

        season.Competition = null;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        //Removed competition from season
```

This feature is called change tracking whereby the data context automatically can detect when a model has changed if it is associated to the data context.
You can read more about this here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/

Comment: Just run the code. You'll see that there's no issue. Yeah, the `Update` call is redundant, but that's not the point.